# Attaching additional lines on top of a Access CSV export

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a process in MS Access where I am exporting the result of a query into a csv format using the DoCmd TransferText method, and using an export specification to contain the field names.

However, I need to attach to the beginning of this file several lines- all of a fixed value- I'm naming this in my code with vbCrLf to separate the several lines I need. How can I append this to the top of the file after it is created. So my file needs to look like this, with the three extra lines for example at the top, with the csv export contents directly below. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

***(need this line 1)

(need this line 2)

(need this line 3)***

field1,field2,field3

x, y, z

Comment: Open a text file, write out the 3 lines you want, then read in the csv and write the contents to the new file after the lines you added.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You might have better chances of getting a good answer if you paste the part of your code that needs debugging and the error or undesired result so far... read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimWilliams has suggested, you will need to use VBA to do this. Below is some code that exports the query to a text file using `.TransferText`, then opens it and imports the data as one chunk, before writing back out the three header lines and the original data:

```
Sub sExportCSV()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strLine1 As String
    Dim strLine2 As String
    Dim strLine3 As String
    Dim strData As String
    Dim intFile As Integer
    strLine1 = "This is line 1"
    strLine2 = "This is the second line"
    strLine3 = "And this is the last line"
    strFile = "J:\test-data\csv.txt"
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qdfExport", strFile, False
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Input As intFile
    strData = Input(LOF(intFile), intFile)
    Close #intFile
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Output As intFile
    Print #intFile, strLine1 & vbCrLf & strLine2 & vbCrLf & strLine3 & vbCrLf & strData
    Close #intFile
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Close #intFile
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sExportCSV", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,